# Send E-Mail When User Profile Fields Updated

Tags: rules, users

I am looking to update my brain regarding a set of rules in Drupal 7. What I am wanting to do is:

1. Send e-mail to arbitrary e-mail address (mine) when a user updates any of their user profile fields.
2. I want the updated fields to appear in the e-mail template.
3. It would be helpful to have the old information showing the new updated field information.
4. Avoid sending e-mail when password is reset or changed.

I am probably missing something basic here with data comparison but thought I would seek out some thoughts on this.

Comment: What is the question here?  What makes you think you're missing something?  Did you try it?  Did it work?  Did it break something?  Did it work but not as you intended?  We can't answer this statement as it stands.

Comment: You're correct. There are actually several questions in here. How about I tackle them one at a time.

The first question should be: 

What is the best way to avoid sending an e-mail after a user profile is updated as a result of a password reset either through the request a new password process or a manual update of the password fields?

Comment: Instead of rephrasing in the comments, please adjust your question so that a meaningful answer or answers can be submitted =)

Comment: Very short answer: check out the rules module.

Comment: Sorry, I have only just returned to Stack Exchange. Using rules to do what I needed to do was the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just Install [Rules Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) and set the conditions something like this:

`Event:` **After updating an existing user account**

`Actions:` **Send a HTML Mail** (`$account` variable is available to send updated values through mail)

*Conditions: If needed*